# CakePHP Migrating Database Rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, git, cakephp

I'm working on an enterprise resource planning software running CakePHP on an internal server.

The system uses Git for team development, works from a MySQL database, CakePHP 2.4.1, PHP 5.4.
I have figured out how to handle incremental database migrating thanks to CakeDC's excellent Migrations plugin.

My problem however, is the following:

While the database structure is migrating fine, I need a solution for migrating some data rows (predefined settings read from the database, ACL structure, things like that).

Is there a solution similar to data structure migration, where I write the required rows into a file, and after I commit with Git, I run a console command that imports the newly added rows, remembers which rows I added, doesn't add them again at the next commit, then another guy on the team pulls the repo, performs the same operation, and has all the required rows? Basically some kind of incremental row migration solution, where each update is timestamped, and the system knows which rows it has to import.

Is there some kind of CakePHP plugin out there that I just can't seem to find, or do I have to write one from the ground up?

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html?

Answer (score 0):

With AclExtra Plugin you can update/sync your acos table from the console:

```
./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```

See:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/part-two.html

For settings permissions from command line you can use AclShell. See the help:

```
./Console/cake acl --help
```